# Wireless card not detected by lspci, lsusb, dmesg

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, devices, pci

I have a Haier HV102H laptop-transformer with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on board, but there is a problem with the WiFi adapter (Broadcom 802.11n Wireless SDIO Adapter). There is no device visible in the output of `lspci` or `lsusb` and no network interface visible in the output of `ifconfig`. WiFi isn’t working. Windows driver installation (by NdisWrapper) and kernel upgrading (up to 4.12) did not help.

It's not a hardware problem: on Windows everything works sucessfully. What can I do to connect Ubuntu to WiFi?

`sudo lshw -c network` outputs nothing.

After putting new file to `/lib/firmware/brcm`:

```
$ dmesg | grep -e sdio
    [    2.746646] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
    [    7.894985] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
    [    8.918931] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
    [    9.927194] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Comment: brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt ???? not brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin?

Comment: Do you have internet access by ethernet, tethered or other means on the Haier? My answer will depend on it.

Comment: @chili555, yes, I can connect Haier to the internet, using USB wire connection.

Comment: See bugs 1691729 and 1578745.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you remove ndiswrapper. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper*
```

Next, let's try to install the missing firmware file.

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/blob/master/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. Post a new message log reading:

```
dmesg | grep -i sdio
```

Comment: no, there is no improvements.

Comment: Any new clues in `dmesg | grep -i sdio`?

Comment: no, only disappeared this line: [    6.847976] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt failed with error -2

Comment: May we also see: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep brcm` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/25767438/

Comment: May we see: `ls  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/` Thanks.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/25774655/

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to make `wlan0` working is to upgrade Ubuntu to 17.10, download one of binary firmware files from [jwrdegoede.danny.cz/brcm-firmware](http://jwrdegoede.danny.cz/brcm-firmware/), rename it to `brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin` and paste it to `/lib/firmware/brcm`.